# AS3 MVC game: Should I separate the data and the game rules in a model?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, oop, model-view-controller

I feel like MVC misses a letter to describe the situation in a game. The model to me seems to consist of two distinct parts:

1. A group of vars that describe the current game state (these will have setters that send out events on change, and getters so that the view can access what changed)
2. The rules of the game that determine what happens once a certain input (i.e. shoot();) has been received by the controller (these will update the group of vars as deemed appropriate)

The view will exclusively be reading from 1 while the controller will be exclusively communicating with 2. This is why I make the distinction and want to divide them up into class1 and class2.

**My questions:**

- I am unsure if I should be making this distinction, since I haven't seen it anywhere.
- If I should; should I make two separate classes, or should I extend class1 with class2?
- Finally, I am having trouble making sure that only class2 (and not the view) can change the variables in class1 (while still being able to send out an event when a value changes). Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reasons you describe are why traditional MVC models typically consist of both data store and application logic.  If you try to partition them, then you run into the situations you are pondering.

If you are worried about views accessing things they shouldn't, you can always push data out in the events to them instead of having them read data in response to an event.  Read up on the Observer pattern.

You can also build your model up from helper classes (a class for state which instantiates Observable, a class for logic, etc) and instantiate them as singletons in the model.  This does not necessarily solve your access control desires, though.

The third question would involve the use of "friends", which some consider a bad OO construct.  The AS3 designers chose not to have friend classes and methods as part of the language like C++.

If you don't have it, the AS3 Design patterns book is a good reference for common ways to handle common issues like the ones you describe.

I would suggest looking into PureMVC.  It isn't an ideal framework for all situations, but it does offer some solutions to the problems you are describing.  In this case, your game state could be stored/accessed in a single proxy, and the logic could/would be split between multiple notifications and commands.  Some people find frameworks restricting, but I find that a well designed framework allows me to concentrate on application specifics rather than how to implement core behaviors.

Comment: Thank you. I will look into PureMVC. Also, I am interested in using my events to push data but I will still have to give my view access to the model in order to listen to these events don't I? Is it possible for the view to listen to events only, and know nothing else about the class that is sending out the events?

Comment: Read up on the Observer pattern, which should answer both questions.  the AS3DP book has a chapter on it, as well as on MVC in the context of an AS3 app.

Answer (score 1):

PureMVC has a StateMachine Utility. This is what you need to handle game state. Basically you define a Finite State Machine that describes all the states your game can be in, the valid transitions between them, and the actions that trigger those transitions.

Actions are sent to the state machine as notifications, and if the action is valid for the current state it will first send out a notification (if defined) for an exiting guard announcement (a notification you define). This gives any interested actor the chance to cancel the transition (i.e. you can't leave the room because you're chained to the floor). Then it sends an entering guard announcement (another optional notification you define). This is another chance for an interested actor to cancel the transition (i.e. you can't enter the room because you don't have the key). If not canceled, then it sends out a state-specific changed announcement, so that interested actors can perform activities specific to having entered this new state.

I haven't coded game logic since the early eighties (in 6502 assembly), so I decided it was time to have fun again. I just finished a touch-focused strategy game using PureMVC and the StateMachine utility, and I must say it was fun to use the tools I use daily on enterprise apps to do a game. Not too heavy, MVC does apply, and the StateMachine made it so crystal clear what was happening and when. It was built for the BB PlayBook, but thanks to AIR, you can check it out and install it on your desktop and try it.

Dungeon Joe: A Touch-focused strategy game.
http://dungeonjoe.com

-=Cliff>